# How to get Maximum value from correlated IDs in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, max

I have scenario where I need to capture dynamic Order-value IDs from response and among those values, I need to select maximum value and pass it to the next request.

How can we achieve this with the help of Jmeter tool?

Comment: Can you add example of response?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following JMeter Variables from the PostProcessor:

```
foo_1=1
foo_2=5
foo_3=10
foo_matchNr=3
```

You can get the maximum value as follows:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request, make sure it goes **after** the PostProcessor which returns your Order-ID values
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   List values = new ArrayList()


   for (int i=1; i <= (vars.get('foo_matchNr') as int); i++) { 
       values.add((vars.get('foo_' + i) as int))
   }

   vars.put('foo_max', Collections.max(values) as String)
   ```
3. Assuming everything goes well you should be able to access the maximum value as `${foo_max}` where required.

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter tests

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick response. This information is really helpful to me.